# Understanding Bash if statement that invokes a command

Tags: bash, if-statement

Does anyone know what this is doing:

```
if ! /fgallery/fgallery -v -j3 /images /usr/share/nginx/html/ "${GALLERY_TITLE:-Gallery}"; then
  mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I understand the first part is saying if `/fgallery/fgallery` directory doesn't exist but after this it it not clear for me.

Comment: It is NOT a directory check. `if` checks the return of the execution of `/fgallery/fgallery ...` If the command returns an `error` condition (e.g. NOT `0`), then `mkdir` is called.

Comment: It means if `/fgallery/fgallery` command doesn't exit with status 0 (it fails), run the `mkdir` command.

Comment: Good catch, I was still stuck in C-mode.

Comment: Frankly, the code looks backwards. Why not simply run `mkdir` first to *ensure* the directory exists, then run `fgallery`?

Comment: The condition in an `if` is *always* a command (possibly preceded by `!` to negate it). A directory existence test, for example, might look like `if [ -d /foo/bar ]`. In that condition, `[` is a command, nearly equivalent to the `test` command; it's not as you might reasonably assume, a built-in part of the shell's syntax. `[` is the most common command to use as a condition, but you can use any command you like.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, we can build an `if` based on the exit status of a command this way:

```
if command; then
  echo "Command succeeded"
else
  echo "Command failed"
fi
```

`then` part is executed when the command exits with 0 and `else` part otherwise.

Your code is doing exactly that.

It can be rewritten as:

```
/fgallery/fgallery -v -j3 /images /usr/share/nginx/html/ "${GALLERY_TITLE:-Gallery}"; fgallery_status=$?
if [ "$fgallery_status" -ne 0 ]; then
  mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html
fi
```

But the former construct is more elegant and less error prone.

---

See these posts:

- [How to conditionally do something if a command succeeded or failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed)
- [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-antipattern)

Comment: I see Thank you very much guys!